# What is the java keyevent field for windows icon?

Tags: java, keyboard-events

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_***windowsicon***);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I need to press windows icon key. But I could not find any virtual key command for or (KeyEvent.VK_***windowsicon***)  some similar command.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered [`KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_WINDOWS)?

Comment: a quick search revealed [VK_WINDOWS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_WINDOWS). http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Previously I tried using `KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS`. but it is not suitable with my expected result. that's  why I asked it as a question. Thanks @MadProgrammer and @f1sh yours responses.

Comment: @PoornaSenaniGamage An explanation would be nice to why it does not suit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Windows start menu pops up on key release, if that's your desired action (check it by slowly pressing and releasing the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key manually).

---

So you must release the key after pressing it,

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS`. It is correct. but it is not suitable with my expected result. so I used this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```